# How many verses are there in Sri TantrAloka?

Tags: tantra, kashmiri-shaivism, abhinavagupta

Sri tantrAloka is a magnum opus text in the Kashmir Shaivism.

How many verses and chapters are there?

Are there any commentaries available ?